# How to resolve unable to load driver class: org.h2.Driver in spring-boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm facing this error :

```
Error creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;      
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
```

Why I'm facing this issue ?

Here is the pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wipro.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the application.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: did you get an error during your tests execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the jar available in runtime.

Modify the scope for h2 dependency in the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @sriramkailash Is this ok ?

Comment: Error resolved : I changed the version of spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.3.3 to 2.0.0 and it worked. Thanks @anish for help

Comment: @sriramkailash, did you change the scope of the dependency?

Comment: @SantosshKumhar yes I changed the scope of the dependency to runtime also.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the h2 driver in the `test` scope which means it is only available during the test case execution.

If you want the h2 driver is also available when executing the application normally , change its scope to the default one (i.e `compile`) should solve the problem :

```xml
       <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by some trailing blank characters after the driver classname in application.properties

This fails (dots in the code snippet below should be read as whitespace chars):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver...
```

This succeeds:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```